# Creating a form on ASP.NET using two seperate models

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with everything up to the most recent updates.
I'm trying to enter in a form with some normal text box answer questions as well as a checkbox answer question, and have all answers be recorded in the same database. Part of my issue is how do I get two separate models asking separate questions using separate databases as references for those questions into one single controller and a view with a list of all of the question answers in one database record? Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, as I am new to ASP.NET this is highly likely. Any input to this issue would be greatly appreciated…

Below is the code for my two models:

Model I:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TessituraForm
{
    public class TessituraFormContext : DbContext
    {
        public TessituraFormContext(DbContextOptions<TessituraFormContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Models.Roles> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model II:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TessituraForm.Models
{
    public class Applicant
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Full Name:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "SI User Name:")]
        [StringLength(10)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Required]
        public string SIUserName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Supervisor:")]
        [Required]
        public string Supervisor { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Badge Number:")]
        [StringLength(8)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Required]
        public string BadgeNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Badge Expiration Date:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        public DateTime BadgeExpirationDate { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Applicant is a(n):")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Required]
        public string ApplicantIsAn { get; set; }

    }
    public class Roles
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AdvancementFundraising { get; set; }
        public string CustomerService { get; set; }
        public string DiscoveryTheater { get; set; }
        public string BusinessOffice { get; set; }
        public string CustomerServiceSupport { get; set; }
        public string ExecutiveStaff { get; set; }
        public string Marketing { get; set; }
        public string Programming { get; set; }
        public string VolunteerCoordinator { get; set; }

        public bool CheckboxAnswer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TessituraForm.Models;

namespace Applicant.Controllers
{
    public class ApplicantController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TessituraFormContext _context;

        public ApplicantController(TessituraFormContext context)
        {
            _context = context;    
        }

        // GET: Applicants
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Applicant.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Applicants/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var applicant = await _context.Applicant
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (applicant == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(applicant);
        }

        // GET: Applicants/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Applicants/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,FullName,SIUserName,Supervisor,BadgeNumber,BadgeExpirationDate,ApplicantIsAn,Roles")] Applicant applicant)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(applicant);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(applicant);
        }

        // GET: Applicants/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var applicant = await _context.Applicant.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (applicant == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(applicant);
        }

        // POST: Applicants/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,FullName,SIUserName,Supervisor,BadgeNumber,BadgeExpirationDate,ApplicantIsAn,Roles")] Applicant applicant)
        {
            if (id != applicant.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(applicant);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ApplicantExists(applicant.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(applicant);
        }

        // GET: Applicants/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var applicant = await _context.Applicant
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (applicant == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(applicant);
        }

        // POST: Applicants/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var applicant = await _context.Applicant.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            _context.Applicant.Remove(applicant);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        private bool ApplicantExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Applicant.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
namespace DatabaseContext.Controllers
{
    public class DatabaseContextController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Roles()
        {
            Applicant objApplicant = newApplicant();
        }
    }
}
```

And View Index Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<TessituraForm.Models.Applicant>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<style>
    body {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }

    h2 {
        color: black;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
</style>

<img src="~/Images/TSA.jpg" alt="TSA" style="position:absolute;left:1372px;top:57px;width:150px;height:75px;" />

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create" style="margin-left:20px;">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SIUserName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Supervisor)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BadgeNumber)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BadgeExpirationDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApplicantIsAn)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Roles)
                </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SIUserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supervisor)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BadgeNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BadgeExpirationDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicantIsAn)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Roles)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Again, my goal is simply to have a form on the web page that has a section with normal text box answers and a checkbox section as well. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can combine Model 1 and Model 2 into a Model 3 that is delivered as a payload to the front end. Or you can perform a separate controller call or ajax call to get model 1 as it seems it is attempting to get data from a DB. If it was a separate controller call, then it would be tied to its own view.

Comment: if you want to combine two different model into one then you can use the concept of viewmodel.http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/how-to-use-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc-with-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to create a new `Model` and then place the other two in that one like below:

```
public class YourNewModel
{
    public Applicant Applicant {get;set;} //note you can declare it here as a List or any how you want
    public Roles Roles {get;set;}
}
```

**Note**
This is just to give you an idea and start you have of, it will also mean changing the methods in your `Controller` suit the approach.
You will also have to pass this `Model` to your view, this way you can have both models at the same place like you wanted.

I hope this helps

Comment: I think I've done this step correctly, I am just having trouble now with changing the controller. Any advice for fixing that aspect? I think part of what is making this instance so complicated for finding a solution is that I am using normal text box questions as well as checkbox questions as well.

Comment: Using text box and checkbox questions shouldn't be a problem as long as you know what you want to achieve